# Códificação UTF-8 não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou com um problema aparentemente simples mas que tem me dado trabalho aqui.

Estou desenvolvendo uma single page *application* utilizando ***AngularJS***, na página `index.html` eu tenho a tag `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`, e como todos os *partials* são injetados dentro desta página, a codificação é replicada para eles, exceto para 1 arquivo, fora isso não estou conseguindo replicar a codificação para o ***Javascript***, *alerts* e mensagens registradas no `console.log` não estão recebendo a codificação.

Alguém sabe o que poderia estar acontecendo ?

Segue codigo html:

```
<html ng-app="WebApp">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        "... demais arquivos css"
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
        <!-- Bibliotecas externas-->
        <!-- Config -->
        <!-- Services -->
        <!-- Controllers -->

        <!-- template do header -->
        <div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>

        <!-- Templates do Angular controlados pelas rotas-->
        <div ng-view></div>

        <!-- template do footer -->
        <div ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia, todos arquivos estao salvos como UTF8 sem BOM?

Comment: Sim, estou salvando com codificação utf-8 no sublime text

Comment: Todos arquivos, tanto os .js quando os .html? Poderia fornecer um exemplo simples do problema pra testar?

Comment: Criei um pastebin pra ficar mais fácil: http://pastebin.com/7704vqHu
Como você irá ver, o conteúdo é injetado dinamicamente na diretiva ng-view, então as partials quando forem renderizadas pelo browser "herdarão" esse index.html. tenho um partial que nada mais é do que uma lista ordenada de buttons que ao ser injetada na ng-view dá erro de codificação dos caracteres com assento, já uma outra que é práticamente identica, o mesmo problema não acontece.

Comment: Mas so tem o html, precisamos do js tambem.

Comment: Já tentou com: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> ?

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas pessoal, acho que o problema tinha alguma coisa a ver com algum erro de configuração do sublime no momento em que os arquivos eram salvos, voltei para as configurações iniciais e salvei em UTF-8 with BOM e deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar a `meta` tag no [formato recomendado](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/dec2002/):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Também confirme que seu servidor não está mandando um cabeçalho `Content-Type` com outro valor pois isso teria precedência sobre a `meta` tag no seu HTML (você pode confirmar usando os dev-tools do seu browser, inspecionando cada requisição).